# How can we remove every characters other than numbers, dot and colon in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am stuck at getting a string from html body

```
<html><head>
<title>Uaeexchange Mobile Application</title></head><body>
<div id='ourMessage'>
    49.40:51.41:50.41       
</div></body></html>
```

I Would like to get the string containing 49.40:51.41:50.41 . I don't want to do it by string advance or index. Can I get this string by specifying I need only numbers,dot(.) and colon(:) in swift. I mean some numbers and some special characters?

I tried

```
let stringArray = response.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
                    NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
                let newString = stringArray.joinWithSeparator("")
                print("Trimmed\(newString)and count\(newString.characters.count)")
```

but this obviously trims away dot and colon too. any suggestions friends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that you need to include "." & ":" in the set that you want to keep.

```
let response: String = "<html><head><title>Uaeexchange Mobile Application</title></head><body><div id='ourMessage'>49.40:51.41:50.41</div></body></html>"

var s: CharacterSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

s.insert(charactersIn: ".:")

let stringArray: [String] = response.components(separatedBy: s.inverted)

let newString: String = stringArray.joined(separator: "")

print("Trimmed '\(newString)' and count=\(newString.characters.count)") 
// "Trimmed '49.40:51.41:50.41' and count=17\n"
```

Without more information on what else your response might be, I can't really give a better answer, but fundamentally *this is not a good solution*. What if the response had been

```
<html><head><title>Uaeexchange Mobile Application</title></head><body>
     <div id='2'>Some other stuff: like this</div>
     <div id='ourMessage'>49.40:51.41:50.41</div>
</body></html>
```

Using a replace/remove solution to this is a hack, not an algorithm - it will work until it doesn't.
I think you should probably be looking for the `<div id='ourMessage'>` and reading from there to the next `<`, but again, we'd need more information on the specification of the format of the response.

Comment: `let newString = stringArray.joined()`

Comment: @LeoDabus I used the OP's code as much as possible, but you are of course correct - no need for either the type or the unnecessary null string parameter. I just added the types for clarity - I think it's good practice on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to use an HTML parser, nevertheless this is a simple solution with regular expression:

```
let extractedString = response.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\\d:.]+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Or the *positive* regex search which is more code but also more reliable:

```
let pattern = ">\\s?([\\d:.]+)\\s?<"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: response, range: NSMakeRange(0, response.utf8.count)) {
    let range = match.rangeAt(1)
    let startIndex = response.index(response.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
    let endIndex = response.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.length)
    let extractedString = response.substring(with: startIndex..<endIndex)
    print(extractedString)
}
```

While the simple (negative) regex search removes all characters which don't match digits, dots and colons the positive search considers also the closing (`>`) and opening tags (`<`) around the desired result so an accidental digit, dot or colon doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `String.replacingOccurrences()` method in other ways, without regex, as follows:

```
import Foundation
var response: String = "<html><head><title>Uaeexchange Mobile Application</title></head><body><div id='ourMessage'>49.40:51.41:50.41</div></body></html>"
let charsNotToBeTrimmed = (0...9).map{String($0)} + ["." ,":"] // you can add any character you want here, that's the advantage
for i in response.characters{
    if !charsNotToBeTrimmed.contains(String(i)){
        response = response.replacingOccurrences(of: String(i), with: "")
    }
}
print(response)
```

Basically, this creates an array of characters which should not be trimmed and if a character is not out there, it gets removed in the `for-loop`

But you have to be warned that what you're trying to do isn't quite right...

Comment: NOTE that trimming an array you're iterating on is not the best thing to do, I only wanted to show you an alternative to the previous answers, which BTW are great!