# How to Deep Link Widget with data pulled from Core Data?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I'm trying to get deep linking working for my app's widgets. The widgets simply display an image from a Core Data entity: Project. I'd like for when a user taps on the widget, it opens up the `ProjectDetailView()` that the image is a member of.
Everything I read says I should be able to add `Link(destination: url)` but I'm not getting anywhere with that. In my app, `project` is pulled from Core Data, but it has no `url` attribute. I feel like it doesn't need one based on the examples I've seen?

The below code gives me the error `Value of type 'FetchedResults<Project>' has no member 'url'` which is true.. it doesn't. I don't understand how to get the url to the `ProjectDetailView()` the image is included in. Thanks so much for taking a look!

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    
}

struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @State var projectImage1: Data = .init(count: 0)
    @FetchRequest(entity: Project.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var project: FetchedResults<Project>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let randomProject: Project = project.randomElement() {
            Link (destination: project.url) {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: randomProject.image1 ?? self.projectImage1) ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "icon"))
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should walk through the [Widget Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10034/) it will walk you through everything there are 3 parts and there is sample code where you can see everything that is called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I have looked at this. Their app is setup very different. `url` is defined in their CharacterDetail.swift. I don't have properties defined for my `Project` because it's a Core Data entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the url in their `CharacterDetail.swift` it is something like `"game:///spouty"` `game` to represent the app the `:///` to [conform to url](https://superuser.com/questions/352133/why-do-file-urls-start-with-3-slashes) and something unique.

So all you need to get a url for for your file is to follow the same pattern.

```
yourApp:///anyUniqueVariable
```

You can achieve this in an `extension` of your object `class` with a computed variable.

```
extension Project{
    var url: URL{
       return URL(string: "yourApp:///\(self.anyUniqueVariable)")
    }
}
```

You keep saying you have a CoreData object that isn't really relevant because the actual connection is made in with SwiftUI and how you "trigger" your `NavigationLink` to the `View` that displays your object.

If you look at the `ContentView.swift` you'll see

```
        .onOpenURL(perform: { (url) in
            self.pandaActive = url == CharacterDetail.panda.url
            self.spoutyActive = url == CharacterDetail.spouty.url
            self.eggheadActive = url == CharacterDetail.egghead.url
        })
```

They are using the `NavigationLink` `init` with `isActive` and triggering the making it `true` when the "received url == the characters url".

You could use that method (might not be the best since you likely have more than 3 objects) or the `init` with `NavigationLink` that has `selection` and set the `tag`/`selection` variable to the `url` you received in `openURL`.

It just depends on how you want to trigger your `NavigationLink`.

Comment: Thank for the added details. It seems like I'd want to create the url extension something like `URL(string: "myApp:///\(self.objectID)")` since the image being displayed is part of the objectID of the entire Project - and the ProjectDetails() view is what I'd want opened when tapping the widget. However wrapping this optional with `!` fails saying unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping, so I question if I'm on thinking about this right.

Comment: `objectID` might have "forbidden" characters. Look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) so see what makes it invalid and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291242/how-can-we-remove-every-characters-other-than-numbers-dot-and-colon-in-swift) details how to trim a `String`

Comment: I had some time to look this up and `URL(string: "app:///\(items.first!.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString)")!` works. Just plain `objectId` does not qualify as something that can go in a `URL`

Comment: Thank for the info. Still struggling to get this working though - the app just opens like normal. Feels like there's still a missing piece.

Comment: The stuff inside the onOpenURL. You have to set the selected item